# How can I create these special fancy bullet points from Word in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, bullets

[image: Image of several bullets]

So, I wanted to make a bullet like the fifth from left in the first row in the image above. You may customize it as you want and can perhaps change colors or shapes or something. Can I please know to make one such a bullet?

[image][image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you put a high resolution image because it is difficult to see the shape of the 4 parts.

Comment: I have pasted a zoomed picture above :) Thank you

Comment: You can try first to draw this with TikZ and then transofrm your plot to a symbol.

Comment: How to do that? I have never used TikZ package and hence I don't know what exactly to do

Answer (score 5):

It's not perfect, but it should give you a starting point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\fsize}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\fsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\specialbullet}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\fsize,y=\fsize]
        \fill [top color=red, bottom color=white] (0,.15) rectangle (.3,.4);
        \fill [left color=violet, right color=white] (.3, .1) rectangle (.65,.35);
        \fill [left color=yellow, right color=white] (.2,.35) rectangle (.5,.6);
        \draw (.4,.05) -- (.4,.65);
        \draw (.2,.2) -- (.75,.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\specialbullet]
    \item An item
    \item Another one
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you created the list symbol of Microsoft office? :-)....Spectacular. Very very nice. But in the violet rectangle is there a shadow?

Comment: that's brilliant Vincent thanks! I appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

An example how to do this with `TikZ` and `enumitem` would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{enumitem}

\newcommand{\myfancylabel}{\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={rotate=45}]%
\node[fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0.5ex] at (0ex,0.5ex) {};%
\node[fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0.5ex] at (0ex,-0.5ex) {};%
\node[fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0.5ex] at (0.5ex,0ex) {};%
\node[fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0.5ex] at (-0.5ex,0ex) {};%
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\myfancylabel]
    \item Test 1
    \item Test 2
    \item Test 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]